# subset using match in r

Tags: r, match, subset

I have a dataset called finalr which list candidates in different universities.I would like to find how many candidates accept offer in each university and rank this in different levels.

```
  yes<-subset(finalr,finalr$Offer.Decision=="yes")
  no<-subset(finalr,finalr$Offer.Decision=="no")
  yes$School<-gsub(" ","",yes$School, ignore.case=T)
  freq<-as.data.frame(sort(table(yes$School),decreasing=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # rank universities in different levels
  platinum<-freq[1:13,]
  gold<-freq[14:26,]
  silver<-freq[27:69,]

 platinum

  [1]  "BostonCollege"               "UniversityofMichigan"           "UniversityofNotreDame"      
  [4]  "PennsylvaniaStateUniversity" "ColumbiaUniversity"             "NewYorkUniversity"          
  [7]  "CarnegieMellonUniversity"    "CornellUniversity"              "DukeUniversity"             
  [10] "GeorgetownUniversity"        "UniversityofVirginia"           "VirginiaTech"               
  [13] "WesleyanUniversity"       

   class(platinum)

   [1] "character"

    platinumschool<-subset(finalr,match(finalr$School,platinum)==TRUE)
    platinumschool$School

   "DartmouthCollege" "DartmouthCollege" "DartmouthCollege" "DartmouthCollege" 
   "DartmouthCollege"
   [6] "DartmouthCollege"
```

when I try to subset all schools from platinum in finalr, the platinumschool only shows records in BostonCollege but misses other. could you guys help me to subset all the records?

Comment: After taking subsets from `finalr`, you remove the spaces from the school names in the `yes` subset with `gsub`. That means the school names in `yes` and in `finalr` no longer match up. I'd recommend removing the spaces from `finalr$School` at the beginning instead of just the `yes` subset halfway through.

Comment: I'd also recommend `%in%` as more readable than `match`: `platinumschool = subset(finalr, School %in% platinum)`. The point of using `subset` instead of `[` is that you don't need to use `$`. Andusingspaceswillmakeyourcodemoreeasytoread.